# connection string in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-config, connection-string

I have a web application which i make on my local host and publish it on different servers.

in the web config of this application i have connectionstrings property like:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHServerDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Now connectionstring data source  has the name of my server and when ever i publish it and run this application on different server i have to change XYZ-PC\SQLEXPRESS to the name of the server..

Is there a way i dont have to do this as it does not feel right..

any suggestions..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing `XYX-PC` with `localhost` provided the instance name is the same.

Comment: Well a drawback of this solution is that you have to host your SQL and your application web application on the same server, what is very rarely the case in production. Also this implies that all other parts of the connection string (host excluded) are the same on all environment. If I refer to the connection string given in example, a production instance is not often SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 2):

If database stands on the same server as IIS, you can use `Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress`

Answer (score 2):

I like to use configSource to pull the connection string out into a separate file, as explained here*:  http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2007/06/07/tip-put-connection-strings-in-their-own-configuration-file.aspx

That way, you can configure each server's connectionStrings.config once, but continue updating their web.config files with a single version that works for all of them.

* Except, I usually name it connectionStrings.config, so it's more obvious for maintenance by others.

Answer (score 0):

The following article could be a solution to your question :
[Handling Multiple Environment Configurations with .NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2007/01/03/handling-multiple-environment-configurations-with-net-2-0.aspx)

Basically, the idea is to use the fact that in your config file you can indicate that some sections have to be read from an external file. Than during the build of your project you copy the right external file according to your environment. I think the link will explain this better.

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string:

```
name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHServerDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Web Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163448.aspx) projects.

In addition to letting you merge everything into a single assembly, it give you the option of doing section-based web.config replacements. We use this on our build server to alter the standard web.config for running in the test environment. As a bonus, you're not limited to just changing connection strings. Anything in the web.config is fair game.